# UIView block animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a custom view (which draws callouts/bubbles) that I currently add as a subview to a UIImageView. It works as intended but I would like to animate the operation with a  spring-like effect. I am using the below code but it does not work (the block gets executed but without animation):

```
/* ViewController */    

UIImageView *iv = self.imageView;

ZGCBubbleView *bubbleView = [[ZGCBubbleView alloc] init];
bubbleView.hidden = YES;
[iv addSubview:bubbleView];

// UIView animation test
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent & UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                 animations:^{

                     bubbleView.hidden = NO;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // tried this
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

I have tried to animate both the hidden property as well as the alpha properties but same result.  I have also tried animating the addSubview method, no difference.  I started out with a more simple animation as proof of concept but that didn't work either.

The above code is executed within a method which is called during the (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated cycle.  Does this have anything to do with this in that the animation is being executed during the main thread? I have read something to that effect but unsure.   Also, I am using auto layout for the UIImageView but didn't think that would matter in this case since the animation is being applied to a custom subview of the UIImageView.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to fade in the view? Is the fading being animated as desired? Or are you trying to animate some other aspect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use alpha.

```
UIImageView *iv = self.imageView;

ZGCBubbleView *bubbleView = [[ZGCBubbleView alloc] init];
bubbleView.alpha = 0;
// bubbleView.hidden = YES;
[iv addSubview:bubbleView];

// UIView animation test
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                  delay:0
 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
  initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent & UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
             animations:^{
                // bubbleView.hidden = NO;
                 bubbleView.alpha = 1;
                 //[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // tried this
             }
             completion:nil];
```

Comment: If it's better to use `alpha` (which it is), why does this code also animate `hidden`?

Comment: Yeah. It makes no sense. Updated the code. Just added a couple of lines without editing much code. :P

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked.  I marked @BhavukJain as the correct answer as animating the alpha property is what allowed the animation to work.  For some reason I thought animating the hidden property should've worked as well but it didn't.

Comment: @Rob Look at the docs for `UIView alpha` and `UIView hidden`. Note what the docs say (or not) about the property being animatable.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I read the reference but pretty sure I have seen anim code using the hidden property. Perhaps in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
UIButton *catchButton = (UIButton *)sender;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut//UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
                 animations:^{
                     catchButton.alpha = 0.4;
                     catchButton.enabled = NO;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: you are trying to animate a view which is hidden.

Comment: you will never see your animation. try with my answer.

Comment: makes no difference.  Actually, the hidden property is just one the few I've tried animating (I've tried adding the subview as part of the animation block as well).   The block executes because I can see my subview, just not in animated fashion.

Comment: can you provide a sample code so that i can observe directly